# Huge MySQL Database -- Do's and Don'ts?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, ubuntu

I'm interested to build a huge database (100s millions of records) using MySQL, to contain stock data in 1-min intervals. The database will contain data for 5000 stocks say for 10 years.

Two concerns:

(1) In the past, I had a problem of "slow insertions" -- meaning, at the beginning the rate of insertions was good, but as the table was filling up with millions of records, the insertion became slow (too slow!). At that time I used Windows and now I use Linux -- should it make a difference?

(2) I am aware of indexing techniques that will help queries (data retrievals) be faster. The thing is, is there a way to speed-up insertions? I know one can turn off indexing while inserting, but then 'building' the indexes post insertion (for 10s of millions of records!) also takes tons of time. any advice on that?

Any other Do's / Don'ts? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What insertion rate do you need? Generally large datasets need lots of internal memory for fast operation so that all indexes can be kept in memory all the time. I have a table with 350 million rows in ms sql server with no insert problems but we only insert around 100 rows a second at most along with roughly the same amount of updates and selects.

Comment: Also we use 48 Gigabyes of memory to ensure indexes are in memory, the indexes on the table is over 24 Gbyte ;)

Comment: Thank you David -- this has been helpful.

Comment: @user54009 just curious, is this data freely available? If so, where can one get it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of index you need and how you generate data. If you are satisfied with single index on time, just stick to that and when you generate data, keep on inserting in ascending order (with respect to the insert time for which you have the index). That way, the reordering required is minimal during insertion. Also, consider partitioning to optimize your queries. It can give you dramatic improvements in performance. Using auto-increment column can help for fast indexing, but then you won't have the index on time if auto-increment column is the only index. Make sure you use innodb storage engine for good performance. If you properly tune your database engine on Linux and keep the design simple, it will smoothly scale without much issues. I think the huge data requirements you talk about is not as difficult to build as it might seem first. However, if you are planning to run aggregate queries (with joins of tables), then that is more challenging.

Comment: Thank you Thava. Suppose one is dealing with many records that have timestamps, inserting many records with time stamps for the years (say) 2001 -- 2010. How does one insert "in order" a new record with a timestamp from (say) 2006?

Answer (score 0):

You could always keep your data in a table with no indexes and then use Lucene (or similar) to index the data. This will keep inserts fast and allow you to query Lucene for fast data retrieval.

Comment: Thank you. Is Lucene indexing faster / better than MySQL indexing?

Comment: Generally it is not a good practice to recommend another product/solution when the asker has a particular one in mind. This is to help with answering the question that the asker actually proposed. This also helps avoid wars where "Forget ABC, use XYZ instead!" occurs.

Comment: @user3262424 The benefit of using something like Lucene or ElasticSearch is that they can scale, while a mysql index is limited to a file on disk, which has to fit in RAM.
The suggestion is not to *replace* MySQL, but to enhance its rather limited indexing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an SSD drive (or array) to store your data, especially if you can't afford to create a box with gigs of memory. Everything about it should be faster.